# Sephardi Halakha

Tags: halacha-theory, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern

Do Sephardim always follow the words the Mechaber ([Maran Yosef Karo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosef_Karo)) in halakha?

Comment: This question depends on your minhag...

Comment: @HachamGabriel Then the answer is "no". You can cite a source and write a more complete answer.

Comment: ROY thought that Geonim Tzeit was Ikkar HaDin IINM.

Answer (score 5):

Mekubal, you recently brought a case of the falling talis where the [Kaf haChaim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14418&st=&pgnum=47&hilite=) says safek brachos lehakel, which is not in line with the Shulchan Aruch who says to make a bracha.

Answer (score 4):

There are certain Sephardim that refrain from eating Kitniyos on Pesach, most notably Jews from Morocco, however the majority of Sephardim still eat Kitniyos.

Answer (score 4):

usually yes, in some special cases no.
sometimes when there's a conflict with cabala we follow cabala
another example is with berachot, even rabenu iosef haim says that we go against the maran when there's a mahloket to do aberacha or not we many times say safek berachot leakel

Comment: Clarification: Rabenu Iosef Haim refers to the individual commonly known as the Ben Ish Hai. His halakhic compendium included opinions from even Askhenazic authorities, which Rav Ovadia Yosef says should never apply to Sephardim. Thus, if you're a traditionalist, you can follow the views and practices of your ancestors even if they contradicted Maran Bet Yosef. But if you're a follower of Rav Ovadia, then it's no question that you should follow the Bet Yosef, the whole Bet Yosef, and nothing but the Bet Yosef.

Comment: Rav ovadia says many times safek berachot leakel even against maran. Some customs that the rama brings are not opposed even by rav Ovadia. I still need to find a sepharadic posek that goes against kimha de pisha

Answer (score 3):

Hacham Ovadia Shelit"a holds (in scattered sources) that we say

"Safek Berachot Neged Maran"- If Maran writes that if you should make a Beracha and two Poskim write that you don't bless we don't follow Maran.

"Sfek Sfeka Neged Maran (Liwyat Hen 42)"- If Maran holds something and there are a lot of Sefekot or different elements surrounding his words we sometimes don't follow him.

"Bimkom Minhag Lo Amrinan Safek Berachot Afilu LeNeged Maran- If Maran writes not to say a Beracha in a case and our Minhag is to say the Beracha we don't follow Maran."

"Im Maran Lo Raa- In some cases we see a Rishon that says something and Maran didn't write or he didn't hold like it, we don't follow Maran because he would have wrote like that Rishon."

There may be more. I just can't remember.